# Something went wrong with processing the default view magneto 2

Tags: magento2, module

**when I try to access "products" in the backend, I"m getting an error.**

[image]

**Debug this**

```
[2020-01-15 05:04:13] main.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 1 at /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:78)"} []
```

Comment: clear ui_bookmark table in your database

Comment: @ShafeelSha can you give more information about it

Comment: delete all logs and then refresh new logs create then read the error there and give details

Comment: @HaFizUmer ok wait mr HafizUmer

Comment: [2020-01-15 05:04:13] main.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 1 at /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:78)"} []

Comment: @ShafeelSha Thank you for reply and suggestion  Its working

Comment: @ShafeelSha can i talk to one any other question

Comment: sir i give you one screenshot but where

Comment: share via this https://snipboard.io/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103321/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-ranjeet-gautam).

Comment: @ShafeelSha please read my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the `ui_bookmark` table of your Magento 2 database, this will reset the grid back to its default and stop the infinite load.